# composition-api and nuxt3 - i don’t have reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a nuxt code that works :

```
<template lang="pug">
div {{ isVisible }} !-- Reactivity OK, isVisible switch from false to true --!
</template>
<script>
export default {


  data() {
    return {
      isVisible: false
    }
  },

  computed: {
    availableLocales() {
      return this.$i18n.locales.filter(i => i.code !== this.$i18n.locale)
    }
  },

  methods: {
    showDropdown() {
      console.log(this.isVisible);
      this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

I try to convert it using composition-api but impossible: it doesn’t work.
I don’t have an error message but I feel like I don’t have responsiveness.
However, the console.log changes the value (but the value is not changed in the template)

```
<template lang="pug">
div {{ isVisible }} !-- Reactivity NOK, isVisible is always false when I click (but with a console.log, the value change) --!
</template>
<script setup>
const { locale, locales } = useI18n()
const switchLocalePath = useSwitchLocalePath()

const availableLocales = computed(() => {
  return (locales.value).filter(i => i.code !== locale.value)
});

let isVisible = ref(false);
const showDropdown = () => {
  console.log(isVisible);
  isVisible = !isVisible;
}

</script>
```

Comment: all refs are proxy objects.  their inner value is found on `.value` property.  change your one line to `isVisible.value = !isVisible.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line

```
isVisible = !isVisible;
```

to

```
isVisible.value = !isVisible.value
```

more info here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref